# How to label a figure outside of the float environment?

Tags: floats, itemize, labels, ref

I am trying to label a figure outside of the float environment. I am using the command \label{} and \ref{}. Unfortunately, Latex does print the correct number of the figure. Does someone know how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{b}
\author{}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
    \item f
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Versuchsaufbau.JPG}
    \label{fig:Versuchsaufbau}
    \captionof{figure}{nj}
    \end{center}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try inserting the  `\label` command *after* `\captionof{figure}{…}`?

Comment: Or, better yet, inside the second argument of `\captionof`? The correct placement for `\label` is `\caption{<stuff>\label{<label>}}` or `\captionof{<type>}{<stuff>\label{<label>}}`. `\label` always references the last increased counter. The counter is increased by `\caption`, that's why you have to put it either inside of or after `\caption`. But if you put it after `\caption` this can lead to inconsistent spacing in some border cases, so inside of `\caption` is the best place (just make sure to not put a space before/after `\label`).

Comment: Thank you! It worked

Comment: And `\label` should be after `\captionof{...}{....}`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, labels must go after captions.

Did you try your MWE? It did not work for me as there were missing packages and no `\ref{...}` so of course there would be no figure number printed in the text body.

```
% figlabelprob.tex  SE 584762

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{b}
\author{}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\section{Another}

\begin{itemize}
    \item f
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Versuchsaufbau.JPG}
    \captionof{figure}{nj}
    \label{fig:Versuchsaufbau}
%    \captionof{figure}{nj}
    \end{center}
\end{itemize}

The figure is \ref{fig:Versuchsaufbau}.

\end{document}
```

The above code prints "The figure is 1." However, if you (un)comment the two `\captionof...` the code will print "The figure is 2" where the "2" refers to the number of the second section.

[image]